# Is there something wrong with cakephp plugin naming convention?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I'm using cakephp 2.5.4 and I tried to create a plugin named ContactManager. I created the folder ContactManager inside Plugin, than created both classes ContactManagerAppController and ContactManagerAppModel inside Plugin/ContactManager/Controller and Plugin/ContactManager/Model respectively. I, then, loaded all the plugins in bootstrap.php with loadAll(). But I got a "Missing Controller" error when I try to access it (localhost/myapp/ContactManager/SomeController).
I changed the name of the folder to contact_manager and try to access it through (localhost/myapp/contact_manager/SomeController) it works just fine!
Did I miss something?

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I made some tests (localhost/myapp/contact_manager/SomeController) points to ContactManager folder. It's only when I call (localhost/myapp/ContactManager/SomeController) that I get the "Missing Controller" error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the convention.
It's written in the docs. You should use snake_case for your URLs

So it's:

```
/myapp/some_plugin/some_controller/some_action
```

And maps to

- SomePlugin plugin
- SomeController controller
- some_action action